# How to install Boost and use with pybind11

Tags: cmake, boost, github-actions, pybind11

I am trying to use GitHub actions on a Python package with pybind11 that uses Boost. I can install Boost but CMake cannot find it when trying to compile the code.

Here is the workflow yaml file

```
name: Build wheels

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main

env:
  BUILD_TYPE: Release

jobs:
  # Build wheels for macOS, Linux, and Windows
  build_wheels:
    name: Wheel for ${{ matrix.os }}-cp${{ matrix.python }}
    runs-on: ${{ matrix.os }}

    strategy:
      # Build the other wheels even if one fails
      fail-fast: false
      matrix:
        os: [windows-latest, ubuntu-latest, macos-latest]
        python: [310]

    steps:
      - name: Checkout repository and submodules
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
        with:
          submodules: true

      - name: Set up Python
        uses: actions/setup-python@v4

      - name: Install boost on Windows
        uses: MarkusJx/install-boost@v2.1.0
        id: install-boost-windows
        with:
          boost_version: 1.78.0
          platform_version: 2019
          toolset: msvc
        if: runner.os == 'Windows'

      - name: Install boost on Linux
        uses: MarkusJx/install-boost@v2.1.0
        id: install-boost-linux
        with:
          boost_version: 1.78.0
          platform_version: 20.04
          toolset: gcc
        if: runner.os == 'Linux'

      - name: Install boost on macOS
        run: |
          brew upgrade
          brew install boost
        shell: bash
        if: runner.os == 'macOS'

      - name: Build wheels
        uses: pypa/cibuildwheel@v2.11.4
        env:
          CIBW_BUILD: cp${{ matrix.python }}-*
          # CIBW_ARCHS_MACOS: x86_64 arm64
          CIBW_ARCHS_MACOS: x86_64
          CIBW_ARCHS_LINUX: auto aarch64

      - name: Show files
        run: ls -lh wheelhouse
        shell: bash
```

and here is my CMakeLists.txt file

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.13)

project(boost_example)

if(APPLE)
  set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++")
endif(APPLE)

add_subdirectory(pybind11)

find_package(Boost COMPONENTS chrono thread serialization REQUIRED)

include_directories (
  /usr/local/include
  ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIR}
  ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/include
  ${USER_INCLUDE_PATH}/database
  ${USER_INCLUDE_PATH} )

link_directories (
  /usr/local/lib
  ${USER_LIBRARY_PATH} )

pybind11_add_module(_boost_example src/boost_example/_boost_example/main.cpp)

target_link_libraries (
  _boost_example PRIVATE
  Boost::chrono
  Boost::thread
  Boost::serialization)
```

The error I get is that CMake cannot find Boost. Below is the relevant part of the error message:

```
CMake Error at C:/Users/runneradmin/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-build-env-bt10hcg3/overlay/Lib/site-packages/cmake/data/share/cmake-3.27/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:230 (message):
          Could NOT find Boost (missing: Boost_INCLUDE_DIR chrono thread
          serialization)
```

So my questions are: How to tell CMake where to find Boost? Should I install Boost using a different method?

Here is a link to a repo with a sample code where you can see the runner error messages:

https://github.com/marcmgame/pybind11_boost_example

It works on MacOs because I use brew to install Boost, but on Windows and Linux it fails because CMake cannot find boost.

Comment: Please, add the relevant **code** to the **question post** itself, this is a requirement of Stack Overflow. A *link* to the code is insufficient for fulfil that requirement. Also add to the question post the **exact error message** you got. See [ask].

Comment: I edited the post to add the relevant code and my questions.

Comment: "The error I get is that CMake cannot find Boost." - Do not *describe* the error message. Instead, add the error message into the question post **exactly** as it is written to you: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359146/why-should-i-post-complete-errors-why-isnt-the-message-itself-enough/359147#359147

Comment: I added the error message to the post, but the best way to see the error message is to click on the GitHub link and see the logs of the runner on the GitHub Actions.

Comment: On Stack Overflow a question post is expected to be **self-contained**. Only in that state it can be useful for future readers. Your question post lacks for a step which calls `cmake`, and where `BOOST_ROOT` variable should be set: https://github.com/MarkusJx/install-boost#boost_root

Comment: But the question is self-contained. The thing is it is a problem when running GitHub actions. I do not call Cmake. It is called by the GitHub actions runner. The example needs a cpp file, a CMakeLists.txt file, a .yml file, and a setup.py file. Additionally, all of these need to be packaged into a Python package.

Comment: If I put the contents of all these files here it would not be useful since you cannot run them in your machine and see the problem. You need to upload that to a GitHub repo and run GitHub actions to see the problem. That is why I added a link to a GitHub repo with a minimal example. By looking at that repo you see the error message and you can try to replicate the problem by cloning it.

Comment: The link you posted works if I were to run CMake myself in the .yml file, but I am not doing that since this is a Python package and setuptools is calling CMake.